# $project $lookup value not shown after $group

Tags: mongodb, nosql, bson, nosql-aggregation

I have 2 related collection which i want to do a `$lookup`.

1. **switches**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "relay" : NumberInt(1), 
    "name" : "Lampu Tengah", 
    "voltage" : 80.0, 
    "duration" : null, 
    "status" : true, 
    "triggered_by" : ObjectId("5e5fd642fce106005319e884"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-01T15:41:36.588+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-01T22:59:39.261+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "relay" : NumberInt(2), 
    "name" : "Kipas Angin", 
    "voltage" : 100.0, 
    "duration" : null, 
    "status" : true, 
    "triggered_by" : ObjectId("5e5fd642fce106005319e884"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-01T15:45:48.099+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-01T15:45:48.099+0000")
}
```

2. **power_usage_month**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e87edffffba850e8d72ce27"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "current" : 19.345, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(123), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-02T15:01:37.521+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-02T15:01:37.521+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e87ee06ffba850e8d72ce28"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "current" : 17.5, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(123), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-03T20:35:09.870+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-03T20:35:09.871+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e87ee0cffba850e8d72ce29"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "current" : 19.345, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(124), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e87ee13ffba850e8d72ce2a"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "current" : 17.5, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(124), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e87ee18ffba850e8d72ce2b"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "current" : 19.345, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(125), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e87ee20ffba850e8d72ce2c"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "current" : 17.5, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(125), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e87ee26ffba850e8d72ce2d"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "current" : 19.345, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(126), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e87ee2dffba850e8d72ce2e"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"), 
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "current" : 17.5, 
    "time_minutes" : NumberInt(126), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-04T01:45:00.000+0000")
}
```

Now i want to "join" these collections using $lookup and `$project` the field i want to show, but apparently the `$project` value won't show after i do a `$group`. Here's my query

```
db.getCollection("power_usages_month").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "_id" : NumberInt(0), 
                "power_usages_month" : "$$ROOT"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "localField" : "power_usages_month.switch_id", 
                "from" : "switches", 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "switches"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$switches", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : "$power_usages_month.switch_id",
                "sum_current" : { 
                    "$sum" : "$power_usages_month.current"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "switch_id" : "$_id", 
                "device_id" : "$switches.device_id",
                "sum_current" : "$sum_current", 
                "voltage" : "$switches.voltage",
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

The `"device_id" : "$switches.device_id",` and `"voltage" : "$switches.voltage"` cannot appear as expected according to the result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"), 
    "sum_current" : 70.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"), 
    "sum_current" : 77.38
}
```

How could it be? Please tell me the fault of the query..

**Edit: Here's my desired result**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"),
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"),
    "sum_current" : 70.0,
    "voltage" : 80.0

}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"), 
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"),
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"), 
    "sum_current" : 77.38,
    "voltage" : 100.0

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the project as the last step after grouping and `$lookup`
also you can handle all of that in the group, 
what you will include in the `$group` will be only available with you in the query, 
but lets say you need to gather the `power_usages_month` docs used by each switch in one array in that switch, 
but you don't need all the info from that `power_usages_month`, you just need the `current` and the `time_minutes` for example

you can do something like that

```
db.powerUsageMonth.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {}
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'switches',
                localField: 'switch_id',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'switch'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$switch'
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$switch._id',
                sum_current: {
                    $sum: '$current'
                },
                switchInfo: {
                    $first: '$switch'
                },
                powerUsageDocs: {
                    $addToSet: '$$ROOT'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                sum_current: 1,
                switchInfo: 1,
                'powerUsageDocs.current': 1,
                'powerUsageDocs.time_minutes': 1,
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

this will return an array of switches with their total current and the switch info (you can do some projection here too if you don't need all the switch info), and the power usages docs related to this switch (after projection)

the result will be something like that

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"),
    "sum_current" : 70,
    "switchInfo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"),
        "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"),
        "relay" : 2,
        "name" : "Kipas Angin",
        "voltage" : 100,
        "duration" : null,
        "status" : true,
        "triggered_by" : ObjectId("5e5fd642fce106005319e884"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-01T15:45:48.099Z"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-01T15:45:48.099Z")
    },
    "powerUsageDocs" : [
        {
            "current" : 17.5,
            "time_minutes" : 125
        },
        {
            "current" : 17.5,
            "time_minutes" : 123
        },
        {
            "current" : 17.5,
            "time_minutes" : 126
        },
        {
            "current" : 17.5,
            "time_minutes" : 124
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"),
    "sum_current" : 77.38,
    "switchInfo" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"),
        "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"),
        "relay" : 1,
        "name" : "Lampu Tengah",
        "voltage" : 80,
        "duration" : null,
        "status" : true,
        "triggered_by" : ObjectId("5e5fd642fce106005319e884"),
        "created_at" : ISODate("2020-04-01T15:41:36.588Z"),
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-04-01T22:59:39.261Z")
    },
    "powerUsageDocs" : [
        {
            "current" : 19.345,
            "time_minutes" : 124
        },
        {
            "current" : 19.345,
            "time_minutes" : 126
        },
        {
            "current" : 19.345,
            "time_minutes" : 123
        },
        {
            "current" : 19.345,
            "time_minutes" : 125
        }
    ]
}
```

> Update
>
> If you just need info about your switch, 
>   also you need to get the watt which is = total current * voltage of each switch, 
>   we can do that in the `$project`, we can add the `$multiply` operator to the `$project` pipeline, which multiplies the voltage of the switch by the total current we just calculated in the `$group` pipeline

```
db.powerUsageMonth.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {}
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'switches',
                localField: 'switch_id',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'switch'
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$switch'
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$switch._id',
                switch_id: { $first: '$switch._id' },
                device_id: { $first: '$switch.device_id' },
                voltage: { $first: '$switch.voltage' },
                sum_current: {
                    $sum: '$current'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                switch_id: 1,
                device_id: 1,
                voltage: 1,
                sum_current: 1,
                watt: { $multiply: [ "$voltage", "$sum_current" ] }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

this will result an array of the form

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"),
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8454bc95c85ca0c33a9463"),
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"),
    "voltage" : 100,
    "sum_current" : 70,
    "watt" : 7000
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"),
    "switch_id" : ObjectId("5e8453c095c85ca0c33a9461"),
    "device_id" : ObjectId("5e7d83efd62c242a11e3ca5e"),
    "voltage" : 80,
    "sum_current" : 77.38,
    "watt" : 6190.4
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems like it wasn't my desired result format. I editted the desired result format, please take a look at :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, could you check it now?
also, don't forget to replace the collectionName 'powerUsageMonth' with your own one

Comment: Great! Thank you for solving my problem :D

Comment: Umm, one more answer sir, i want to add multiply value after that ````voltage```` field, my query is 
````watt: {$first: {$multiply: ["$sum_current", '$switch.voltage']}}````
But it cannot call the sum_current group, how to achieve that?

Comment: okay, I've just updated my answer again to add the watt of each switch

Comment: Ah i see so it should move to a $project, right, thank you again~